# Android Normal Application says it is System Application - Cannot uninstall

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android application and it was always working like a charm.
But yesterday I wanted to manually remove the application from my phone via uninstall. The uninstall dialog popped up, run through and closed again but the application was still there.
I tried it several time, also restarted my phone but I still could not delete the application.
After some time the dialog said "cannot uninstall system application". 
My application is a standard android application which does not have to do anything with a system application at all. 
I was searching for answers but could not find anything helpful.
So do you guys have any suggestions?
(My Phone is not rooted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what the problem was.
Somehow eclipse installed the application for every user on the smartphone.
With Lolipop you have the possiblity to have several users and switch between them.
So the only thing I did is I selected "uninstall for all users" and the application was removed.
You can find the option in the installed apps list.

Sorry for the question turned out to be a quite stupid one.